# Excel User Defined Function within another UDF not updating

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first post so I hope this is all ok....I've looked elsewhere and can't find this specific question anywhere.

*Background:*

Say I have an experiment and there are 4 ways in which it could fail, each fail has a different code:
'R1' --> 'R4' with
'R' = no fails

I originally wrote 4 separate UDFs and then in my worksheet cell have nested IF functions to test the output of each and return the relevant fail code (or 'R' if it passes). With all the parameters required, this results in quite a lengthy Excel formula.

Each UDF has several parameters based on values in several cells. My idea was to create a 'Master Function' that would just call each of the UDFs and return the correct code. This way, in the cell it would just look like (e.g.) =Master()

*Question:*

I started by putting the cell ranges into the Master Function and then passing them into the functions as parameters (e.g.)

```
Function Master()

Dim p1 as Range
Dim p2 as Range

Set p1 = Range("A1")
Set p2 = Range("B1")

myR1 = UDF1(p1)
myR2 = UDF2(p2)

If myR1 <> "" Then
Master = myR1
...

End Function
```

However, the UDFs don't update when the value in A1 or B1 changes. I realise that the return value will only change if the cell is passed as a parameter, but I thought I was passing the parameters into UDF1 and UDF2??

Obviously if I write:

```
Function Master(p1 as Range, p2 as Range)

myR1 = UDF1(p1)
myR2 = UDF2(p2)

End Function
```

It works for me but I will end up having to pass loads of parameters into this Master Function which, I can do, but I was wondering if there was another way?

Note - I would like to avoid using Application.Volatile if possible.

Like I said, this is my first post so I hope I've followed all forum rules etc. I also hope I was clear!

Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion you already stated both possible ways. Either passing ranges or Application.volatile.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue.  Application.Volatile didn't solve it for me.

Comment: Instead of naming a function UDF you should use a proper descriptive name.